# Conditional Expectation for random variable multiplied by indicator function

Tags: probability, expected-value, conditional-expectation

I went through the following formula and I want to make sure if I'm missing something.
For a random variable $X$ there is a vector of related covariates $Y,$ then for high threshold $u$ the following is true
$$E\left(\log\left(\frac{X}{u}\right).1_{X>u}\mid Y=y\right)=E\left(\log\left(\frac{X}{u}\right)\mid X>u,Y=y\right)P(X>u\mid Y=y)$$

where $1_{X>u}$ is an indicator function that takes the value $1$ if $X>u$ and $0$ otherwise. I don't understand why the probability is added?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We illustrate a simpler example.  Suppose $X \sim \operatorname{Exponential}(\lambda = 1)$, with density $$f_X(x) = e^{-x} \mathbb 1 (x > 0).$$  Then for $u > 0$, $$\operatorname{E}[X \mathbb 1(X > u)] = \int_{x=0}^u 0 e^{-x} \, dx + \int_{x=u}^\infty x e^{-x} \, dx = (u+1)e^{-u},$$ but $$\operatorname{E}[X \mid X > u] = \frac{1}{\Pr[X > u]} \int_{x=u}^\infty x f_X(x) \, dx = \frac{(u+1) e^{-u}}{e^{-u}} = u + 1.$$  The difference lies in the fact that the function $$X \mathbb 1 (X > u) = \begin{cases} 0, & X \le u \\ X, & X > u, \end{cases}$$ whereas $X \mid X > u$ does not allow for $X \le u$ because it is *given* that $X > u$.

Comment: Thanks @heropup, so I see that eventually $$E\left(\log\left(\frac{X}{u}\right).1_{X>u}\mid Y=y\right)=E\left(\log\left(\frac{X}{u}\right)\mid X>u,Y=y\right)P(X>u\mid Y=y)$$
holds as $$E\left(\log\left(\frac{X}{u}\right)\mid X>u,Y=y\right)=\frac{E\left(\log\left(\frac{X}{u}\right).1_{X>u}\mid Y=y\right)}{P(X>u\mid Y=y)}$$